# Condition inside a count -SQL

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to write a condition inside a count statement where it should only count the entries which do not have an ENDDATE. i am looking for writing the condition inside the count as this is a very small part of a large SQl Query

Comment: Please note that StackOverflow is not a free code-writing service. Unless you let us know exactly how to replicate your issue, and where you are having trouble, it will be difficult to for us to help you. Please describe what you have already tried, in as much detail as possible, and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

sample query,

select product, count(*) as quantity

from table

where end_date is null

group by age

This query lists quantity for each product which do not have an end date

Answer (score 0):

One method uses conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when end_date is null then 1 else 0 end) as NumNull
. . .
```

Another method is just to subtract two counts:

```
select ( count(*) - count(end_date) ) as NumNull
```

`count(end_date)` counts the number that are *not* `NULL`, so subtracting this from the full count gets the number that *are* `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Uhmmmm.

It sounds like you are looking for conditional aggregation.

So, if you have a current statement that's sort of working (and we're just guessing because we don't see *anything* you have attempted so far...)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
  FROM mytable t
```

And you want another another expression that returns a count of rows that meet some set of conditions...

and when you say "do not have an ENDDATE", you are refderring to rows that have an ENDDATE value of NULL (and again, we're just guessing that the table has a column named ENDDATE. Every row will have an ENDDATE column.)

We'll use a ANSI standards compliant CASE expression, because this would work in most databases (SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, Postgres... and we don't have clue what database you are using.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN t.ENDDATE IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS cnt_null_enddate
  FROM mytable t
```